# How to find the total count of column values?

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have a table with columns EmpCode,Lnumber,date

```
   EmpCode    Lnumber        Date
   .........  .........    ..........
       a          5        2015-01-01
       a          5        2015-01-01
```

I want to find the total number of `Lnumber`

```
Expected output=Lnumber=10(5+5)
```

I tried with Count query but it shows it count like 2. How can I get its total count as out put

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [Sum](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187810.aspx)

```
Select Sum(Lnumber) from xyztable
```

Answer (score 2):

try Sum function of sql server

```
select Sum(Lnumber) as output from yourtable
```

Answer (score 2):

If you simply want the sum irrespective of employee, try the below.

```
SELECT SUM(Lnumber) Lnumber
FROM YOURTABLE
```

If you want to get sum for each employee you can try this

```
SELECT EmpCode,SUM(Lnumber) Lnumber
FROM YOURTABLE
GROUP BY EmpCode
```

Answer (score 2):

Count will give you the number if records. you can use SUM to get the total value of the numbers.

```
select SUM(Lnumber) as Total from tableName
```

Answer (score 2):

If `Lnumber` *can* contain `nulls` the syntax is

```
select sum(coalesce(Lnumber, 0)) -- nulls are treated as zeros
  from MyTable
```

if `Lnumber` *can't* be `null` the query can be simplified to

```
select sum(Lnumber) 
  from MyTable
```